# java com.mongodb.DBCollection create a background index

Tags: java, mongodb, collections, indexing

I am creating a mongodb Collection through my Java code, i want to create index on this collection, however as per the online tutorials i realized that creating a background index is preferable as it would not lock the collection for creation of index.
the Code for the same is as below:

```
 DBCollection ActivityLogCollection = this.db.createCollection(this.mrCollName, new BasicDBObject().append("capped", false));
 ActivityLogCollection.ensureIndex("act");
```

How do i ensure that this gets created as a background collection. i tried it using

```
DBObject indexOptions = new BasicDBObject();
indexOptions.put("background", true);
```

and then passing it as

```
ActivityLogCollection.ensureIndex(indexOptions,"act");
```

However what this did was creating an index with key as "background".

Any help on the same would be highly appreciated.

Thanks,

Vaibhav

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass the index options as the *second* parameter to `ensureIndex`:

```
DBObject indexFields = new BasicDBObject("act", 1);
DBObject indexOptions = new BasicDBObject("background", true);
ActivityLogCollection.ensureIndex(indexFields, indexOptions);
```

Comment: I am just being curious here, the above code works for me, however as per the available articles background index does not lock the collection when an index is created, so ideally this should be a case when we are creating an index on a collection that already exists and has enormous data, would creating a background index on any new collection which is initially empty make any difference over the default non-background index.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting all the index options together in one `DBObject` itself:

```
DBObject indexOptions = new BasicDBObject();
indexOptions.put("background", true);
indexOptions.put("name", "act");
```

Now specify:

```
ActivityLogCollection.ensureIndex(indexOptions);
```

Answer (score 0):

ensureIndex() method was removed in MongoDB v5.0

Instead, use `createIndex()` by passing options as shown below,

```
ActivityLogCollection.createIndex(new BasicDBObject("act", 1), new BasicDBObject("background", true));
```